# Why is the return value of the AJAX call 'undefined'?

Tags: php, jquery

I have following code

```
function getUser(){
    var user;

    $.post('php/function/getSessionData.php', {
        action: "getUser" 
    }).done(function(response){
        user = $.parseJSON(response);
    });
    console.log(user); //in console its displayed as object like excepted.
    return user;
}
```

This function calls a php file and should return data what is stored in the session array.

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case "getUser":
                    echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']);
                    break;
        default: break;
    }
?>
```

Actually everything works fine. Data is recived and all....

now in my jquery i have some like this to call this all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".myButton").on("click", function(){

        console.log(getUser());

    });
});
```

of course there is some more source but this part is my problem.

it returns 'undefined'. Usual i can pass objects by return don't i ?

why does my source returns 'undefined' ?

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous.!

Comment: and that means for me ???

Comment: The A in `AJAX` stands for **Asynchronous** meaning that you do not get a result from ajax immediately. Statements after an ajax call will be executed long before those in the success callback.

Comment: Your `getUser()` function is not within the scope of of your click function.

Comment: so i have to use success in jquery to may handle this ?

Comment: i guess you guys are right with the duplicate... didn't know what i was searching for :)